# Google is not indexing an original post, but indexing pagination page and facebook post

Tags: seo, google, sitemap

I built https://talksub.com/, and I am having trouble with SEO for individual posts.

I implemented `JSON-LD` and have all necessary meta tags like (`title`, `description`, `canonical url`, `og`, `twitter` ...) for every page.

However, most posts are not showing up on google search.

For example, [this post](https://talksub.com/post/peKrs9wYgulWlcXgchJbhlH) does not show up on google search, even if I search with its h1 title `"We now support multiple post drafts"`. See [Google search result](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS812US812&ei=ifqCXtHMIoPe-gTJqoLgDQ&q=%22We+now+support+multiple+post+drafts%22&oq=%22We+now+support+multiple+post+drafts%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECAAQRzoFCCEQoAE6BQghEKsCUI4HWL0WYOsXaABwAngAgAFhiAGsAZIBATKYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiRtZabocToAhUDr54KHUmVANwQ4dUDCAs&uact=5).

[image: Google search result]

If you look at the search results, it shows a facebook post and pagination page on our site, but not the post itself.

What am I missing on my post page?

Should I have a sitemap for every post? If so, how do you keep track of sitemap if there are 10,000+ posts?

Sitemap: https://talksub.com/sitemap.xml

robots.txt: https://talksub.com/robots.txt